# Duplicated declarations. error: conflicting types for ‘functionname’

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to include these files to my main C code:

**who.c:**

```
/* who3.c - who with buffered reads
 *    - surpresses empty records
 *    - formats time nicely
 *    - buffers input (using utmplib)
 */
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <utmp.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <time.h>
#include    "utmplib.h"

#define SHOWHOST

void show_info(struct utmp *);
void showtime(time_t);

int Who()
{
    struct utmp *utbufp,    /* holds pointer to next rec    */
            *utmp_next();   /* returns pointer to next  */

    if ( utmp_open( UTMP_FILE ) == -1 ){
        perror(UTMP_FILE);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ( ( utbufp = utmp_next() ) != ((struct utmp *) NULL) )
        show_info( utbufp );
    utmp_close( );
    return 0;
}
/*
 *  show info()
 *          displays the contents of the utmp struct
 *          in human readable form
 *          * displays nothing if record has no user name
 */
void show_info( struct utmp *utbufp )
{

    printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_name);      /* the logname  */
    printf(" ");                    /* a space  */
    printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_line);      /* the tty  */
    printf(" ");                    /* a space  */
    showtime( utbufp->ut_time );            /* display time */
#ifdef SHOWHOST
    if ( utbufp->ut_host[0] != '\0' )
        printf(" (%s)", utbufp->ut_host);   /* the host */
#endif
    printf("\n");                   /* newline  */
}

void showtime( time_t timeval )
/*
 *  displays time in a format fit for human consumption
 *  uses ctime to build a string then picks parts out of it
 *      Note: %12.12s prints a string 12 chars wide and LIMITS
 *      it to 12chars.
 */
{
    char    *ctime();       /* convert long to ascii    */
    char    *cp;            /* to hold address of time  */

    cp = ctime( &timeval );     /* convert time to string   */
                    /* string looks like        */
                    /* Mon Feb  4 00:46:40 EST 1991 */
                    /* 0123456789012345.        */
    printf("%12.12s", cp+4 );   /* pick 12 chars from pos 4 */
}
```

**who.h:**

```
#ifndef WHO_H
#define WHO_H

/* This file was automatically generated.  Do not edit! */
int Who();
void showtime(time_t);
void showtime(time_t timeval);
void show_info(struct utmp *);
void show_info(struct utmp *utbufp);

#endif
```

**utmplib.c:**

```
/* utmplib.c  - functions to buffer reads from utmp file 
 *
 *      functions are
 *              utmp_open( filename )   - open file
 *                      returns -1 on error
 *              utmp_next( )            - return pointer to next struct
 *                      returns NULL on eof
 *              utmp_close()            - close file
 *
 *      reads NRECS per read and then doles them out from the buffer
 */
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <fcntl.h>
#include        <sys/types.h>
#include        <utmp.h>

#define NRECS   1
#define NULLUT  ((struct utmp *)NULL)
#define UTSIZE  (sizeof(struct utmp))

static  char    utmpbuf[NRECS * UTSIZE];                /* storage      */
static  int     num_recs;                               /* num stored   */
static  int     cur_rec;                                /* next to go   */
static  int     fd_utmp = -1;                           /* read from    */

utmp_open( char *filename )
{
        fd_utmp = open( filename, O_RDONLY );           /* open it      */
        cur_rec = num_recs = 0;                         /* no recs yet  */
        return fd_utmp;                                 /* report       */
}

struct utmp *utmp_next()
{
        struct utmp *recp;
        //struct utmp *nextRecp;
        int match = 0;
        if(recp->ut_type == USER_PROCESS)
        {
            recp = ( struct utmp *) &utmpbuf[cur_rec * UTSIZE];
        }

        while(recp->ut_type!= USER_PROCESS)
        {


        if ( fd_utmp == -1 )                            /* error ?      */
                return NULLUT;
        if ( cur_rec==num_recs && utmp_reload()==0 )    /* any more ?   */
                return NULLUT;
                                        /* get address of next record    */

        recp = ( struct utmp *) &utmpbuf[cur_rec * UTSIZE];
        cur_rec++;
        }

        return recp;





}

int utmp_reload()
/*
 *      read next bunch of records into buffer
 */
{
        int     amt_read;

                                                /* read them in         */
        amt_read = read( fd_utmp , utmpbuf, NRECS * UTSIZE );   

                                                /* how many did we get? */
        num_recs = amt_read/UTSIZE;
                                                /* reset pointer        */
        cur_rec  = 0;
        return num_recs;
}

utmp_close()
{
        if ( fd_utmp != -1 )                    /* don't close if not   */
                close( fd_utmp );               /* open                 */
}
```

**utmplib.h:**

```
#ifndef UTMPLIB_H
#define UTMPLIB_H

/* This file was automatically generated.  Do not edit! */
utmp_close();
int utmp_reload();
struct utmp *utmp_next();
utmp_open(char *filename);

#endif
```

But I can not compile these files, I'm getting this error:

```
who.h:9:6: error: conflicting types for ‘show_info’
 void show_info(struct utmp *utbufp);
```

I didn't write these two file. First of all why there are duplicated declarations? And how can I fix it?

I generated header files using [makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/).

Actually these files are working example for `who` command in Linux or basic version of who.c in GNU core utils. [*Taken from here*](https://github.com/jstocke2/who4.c)

who.c compiling without any error and working seamlessly(if you change Who function name with main):

```
cc who.c utmplib.c -o who
who
```

Comment: This `struct utmp *utbufp, *utmp_next();` is terrible coding style! Also, why do you so many prototypes for your functions?

Comment: What do you mean with prototype? I'm new in C actually.

Comment: Function declarations for example `void showtime(time_t);` and `void showtime(time_t timeval);` are exactly the same (*almost*).

Comment: Yeah this is what I asking why there are two declerations?

Comment: Declarators are a very basic concept in programming languages in general and C in detail. You have to understand them quite well to master any non-trivial code in C. Asking questions here will not help to get get the whole picture. Better read a good book and learn.

Comment: Note that `who.h` is not self-contained because it declares functions which use type `time_t` but does not ensure that `time_t` is defined by `#include <time.h>`.  Most likely, you've got the same problem with `struct utmp`; it must be declared to exist outside the prototypes in `who.h`, preferably by `#include <utmp.h>`.  This is probably the source of your compilation problems.

Comment: Also note that you've not defined a prototype for the function `Who()`; you've merely declared it as function that exists with an indeterminate (but not variadic — no ellipsis `...` in the function definition) argument list and returns type `int`.  To give a prototype indicating no arguments, use `extern int Who(void);` (or drop the `extern` if you prefer).

Comment: when prototyping functions with no parameters, use `void` between the parens, otherwise the compiler makes the assumption that there are parameters, and you just haven’t' specified them (a very risky methodology)

Comment: the function: `utmp_close()` is not a valid signature in modern compilers.  Suggest: `void utmp_close()`  similar considerations exist for the function: `utmp_open()` signature should be: `void utmp_open()`

Comment: when indenting, do not use tabs,  because every wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows many indent levels across the page

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.    For me, all the (many) resulting output messages from the compiler were easy to fix, except: in the function: `utmp_next()`, this message: "warning: 'recp' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]"

Comment: the file: `utmplib.c` is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  which is needed for the `read()` function.

Comment: the file: `utmplib.h` contains some `#define` statements.  those statements and their subsequent usage just clutter the code, hide the actual code elements and lead to confusion.  Strongly suggest removing the `#define` statements and using the actual text.

Comment: the function: `Who()` checks the returned value from the call to `utmp_open()` and exits if that call fails.  The `utmp_open()` is not called anywhere else.  Therefore, the function: `utmp_close()` never needs to check if the file is actually open before calling `close()`

Comment: why does the function: `Who()` contain a prototype for the function: `utmp_next()` when that function is already prototyped in the `utmplib.h` header file, which is #include'd in the file that contains the `Who()` function?

Comment: the function:" `showtime()` contains a prototype for `ctime()`  that prototype is already in the `time.h` header file.  that header file should be #include'd at the top of the `who.h` header file, for the references to the `time_t` type.  so should already be available so no need to have a separate prototype.  And the prototype is not correct, it should be: `char    *ctime( time_t );`

Comment: in the function `utmp_reload()`, the variable `amt_read` receives the returned value from a call to `read()` and `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, so the variable should be declared as `ssize_t amt_read;`

Comment: the global variable `cur_rec` is declared as an `int` but is always used with `size_t` values, so should be declared : `size_t cur_rec;`

Comment: the calculation of variable: `num_recs` will always be 0 or 1,  Is this really what you want.?  (remember the prior call to `read()` only ask for the number of bytes in the `struct utmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override flags when using automake, e.g., 'make CFLAGS=-O0 file.o' to disable optimization for file.c

Comment: Automake making `-02` flag how can I remove that flag: `gcc  -g -O2   -o main main.o asciiart.o who.o utmplib.o`

Comment: I think you can override flags when using automake, e.g., 'make CFLAGS=-O0 file.o' to disable optimization for file.c

Comment: Yeah, I found that too, -O0 flag is the real answer. Please update your answer.